# Transforming values of unknown keys in SQL

Tags: sql, transform

Given this table: (A, B, C, ... are arbitrary key names)

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
|  false  |   true  |  12345  | "string"|  true   | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there any way to transform this **without knowing the keyset** to:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
|    0    |    1    |  12345  | "string"|    1    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

tldr; I want to change all occurrences of 'true' (not a string) and 'false' (not a string) to 1 and 0, respectively. I do not have a list of keys.

Comment: You sure can. Please post the `create table ...` statement so we can help you.

Comment: What's the specific database?

Comment: You can't change values in a column without knowing the name of the columns.

Comment: You could fetch all the column definitions for the table from the data dictionary and create an `UPDATE` from there. Possibly depending on the type of the columns (e.g. if it's `boolean`) or generating expressions, that examine the contents (like checking if a string value reads 'false', then replace it with '0'). And then execute that statement. The umbrella term is "Dynamic SQL" here, check what you can find for your DBMS for that.

Comment: You could use MySQL — in that database, false is literally the integer 0 and true is the integer 1. MySQL doesn't have a true boolean data type. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @GordonLinoff says, you can't reference columns without knowing the names of the columns.

It's the same in any other programming language:

> "I'd like to change the value of a variable, but I don't know the variable name."
>
> "Well, that must be very hard for you. After you find out the variable name, you can change it."

It's the same way in SQL. You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to discover column names if you don't know them. You'll have do that before you can form an SQL query against the columns.

- Microsoft SQL Server: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- MySQL: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html)
- PostgreSQL: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)

Other brands of databases have similar metadata tables, but use different names for them.